# Different proxy per tab firefox selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox, proxy

What I am trying to achieve is to open up multiple tabs in firefox using selenium. To each tab, I want to assign an individual proxy which the tab will use. Is this possible?

Comment: did u find answer for this ?

Comment: @JeyaKumar have not found anything. Please let me know if you fix it!